# Order parameter to quantify clustering?

Tags: magnetic-fields, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

I have a 1D system containing $N$ particles having positions $\{x_1(t),x_2(t),\dots,x_N(t)\}$ in a box of size $L$ with periodic boundaries. The number of particles is conserved.

The dynamics of the particles are governed by some equations with the interaction strength between particles characterized by some control parameter $C$.

Two phases emerge as $C$ is varied. There is an "unordered" phase, where particles behave independently, then there is an "ordered" phase, where particles behave collectively as a result of the interactions.

Putting the $x_i$ on the horizontal axis and splaying out the $y$ coordinate to facilitate visualization, the small $C$ unordered phase appears like this: 
[image]
while the large $C$ ordered phase develops multiple clustered domains 
[image]

I would like to quantify the amount of clustering with some order parameter $\Psi$. Were there only one cluster, the standard deviation of position would do a good job:

$$ \Psi = \sqrt {\langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x \rangle^2}.$$
For the unordered case it would be $L$ and for the ordered case it would be $l$ -- the size of the spatial cluster.

Does anyone have a recommendation of an order parameter to study clustering in the case with many clusters? Can I generalize from the standard deviation somehow? Is there an analogous problem in magnetism I could study?

Comment: Can you specify your system a bit more? What is on the vertical axis in the plot? Particle density? Is total number of particle conserved?

Comment: @Icv thanks, I added some clarification. Please let me know if you have more questions. The vertical axis just facilitates visualization as the particles exist on the line (horizontal axis) having some positions $x_i\in[0,L]$. There are periodic boundary conditions and the number of particles is conserved.

Comment: Yes, [entropic uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_uncertainty#Entropy_versus_variance_bounds) accommodates clustering around multiple centers.  Please use "disordered" rather than "unordered".